# How to develop NPM module for Ionic

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework, npm, rollupjs

I am developing library for Ionic 2, that should be installed via NPM, but i can't do this in classic way. If you want to develop module you can use *npm link* command to link module to your project where you want test and develop it, but in Ionic it everytime fall on compilation error, when is module linked using *npm link*.

This is error that i get evertime:

```
[10:14:15]  Error: Could not resolve entry (./.tmp/app/main.dev.js)
at /Users/daniel/ionic/cache-test/node_modules/rollup/dist/rollup.js:8602:28
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:103:7)
```

So, is there any trick how to develop and test NPM module in Ionic 2?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We did experiment with this, to share ngrx-based core module in between a web Angular2 app and an Ionic2 mobile app:
https://github.com/benorama/ngrx-demo-apps

However, we did not manage to make it work through `npm link`, only with `npm pack/install`.

The trick is to define your external lib in a custom `rollup.config.js`. You can find more info here:
http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/resources/third-party-libs/
http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/resources/app-scripts/

Comment: The answer is outdated, any updated sources with no broken links?